# PySpark and pyArrow - Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow - Array of Struct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I use Arrow optimization in pySpark in order to make faster data transfer between Python and JVM. I add the corresponding param to my Spark session.

```py
app_name = "App"

spark_conf = {

    # some other params

    'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled': 'true'
}


builder = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName(app_name)
)

for k, v in spark_conf.items():
    builder.config(k, v)
    
spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

Try `toPandas` the following DataFrame

```py
df.printSchema()
"""
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dtm: long (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- campaign_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cr_pred: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ctr_pred: float (nullable = true)
"""

df.toPandas()
```

Got an error

```
toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow: ArrayType(StructType([StructField('campaign_id', LongType(), True), StructField('cr_pred', FloatType(), True), StructField('ctr_pred', FloatType(), True)]), True)
```

I found that Arrow supports struct arrays ([see docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.StructArray.html)) but, it seems, Spark does not know how to convert the formats.

Any ideas how to use pyArrow optimization with such nested data structures?

Comment: My current own solution - convert nested structures to strings

Comment: Turn off apache arrow optimization.  Had the same issue with pandas.read_excel().  I have no control over the content.

Comment: Thanks, well, the idea was to keep using arrow due to significant performance gain) from these perspective my current solution to use strings is better than just power off arrow..